# safe string insertion code for stringbuilder

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

```
"PRD_DEV.BGD..NaR"

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(symbol);
builder.insert(12, line); //add third part of symbol
```

I am adding my third part of the above string with the code above. What is a safer way to insert a string into the third part of the above string `PRD_DEV.BGD..NaR` after the second `.` So that future changes to string won't affect my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure there are a total of 3 dots, you could try:

```
builder.insert(builder.lastIndexOf("."), line);
```

If you know there's only one "part" missing, you could use:

```
builder.insert(builder.indexOf("..") + 1, line);
```